# how to include the AIDL build output to the Javadoc task in Gradle?

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio, javadoc, android-gradle-plugin

I have a javadoc task defined as following:

```
task androidJavadocs(type: Javadoc) {
    source = android.sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs
    classpath += project.files(android.getBootClasspath().join(File.pathSeparator))
}
```

But, this doesn't include the source code generated by AIDL compiler under "build/generated/source/aidl/debug".

Is there any sourceSet definition representing this group of generated source? What is the most elegant way to include it in the Javadoc task?